# Adding a grid on the east region of a page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a formPanel which contains many objects:

```
var itemPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 75, 
    frame:true,
    region:'left',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 500,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items : [comboTariff,otherFieldset,choiceFieldset,currencyCheck,otherFieldsetcu,changeField,otherFieldsetcargo,dr]    
});
```

And I have another FormPanel which contains itemPanel and a gridPanel:

```
var resultPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
labelWidth: 75, 
    frame:true,
    title:'Tariff & Surcharge Updates: New Item',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 800,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items : [itemPanel,ItemGrid]
});
```

I want itemPanel to be on the center of the page and ItemGrid to be on the right of the page.
here is the structure of my grid :

```
var ItemGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: eastStore,
    autoShow : true,
    title : 'Choix des parametres',
    titleCollapse: true,
    collapsed : true,
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    loadMask: true,
    autoScroll:true,
    region : 'east',
    width : 800,
    style:"{font-size:  8px;} ",
    stripeRows: false,
    frame:false,
    height : 150,
    border:false,
    columns [etc etc...]});
```

and here is my layout :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: "border",
        id: 'movieview',
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [{
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 0,

            plain:true,
            defaults:{autoScroll: true},

            items: [resultPanel,otherPanel,templatePanel]

       }]
    })
        function handleActivate(tab){
        alert(tab.title + ' was activated.');
        }


})
```

;

Nothing appears on my page, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you included ItemGrid. You created it but didn't include into your viewport.

Comment: @sha It's included in resultPanel

Answer (score 0):

1. Your border layout is defined for the viewport. Your `ItemGrid` is not in a border layout. Region ´east´ is valid only if the parent panel has border layout.
2. Your `resultPanel` should be FormPanel. You can define it as `panel` or `container` with `hbox` layout